# How to remove multiple dynamically generated elements at the same time by their class name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamic

I am doing an e commerce project, and for the shipping part, I let the user enter one area place asssociated with a price and then these two values are displayed with a remove button.
The user can generate multiple times of these three elements.(and at each of these three generated elements, there are two input hidden to handle the values and then process that data with php)
When clicked on the remove button, i would like to remove the entered area+the price+the remove button by their similar class name.
But how to do that when it is dynamically generated ?
This is the HTML part:

```
        <label for="places">Places/area : </label>
        <input type="text" name="ps_places" id="ps_places" value="" >
        <label for="ps_price" "> Price : </label><input type="text" name="ps_price" id="ps_price" value="" >
        <button type="button" onclick="ps_add()">OK</button>
        <div id="display1"></div>
```

And the javascript part:

```
function addElement(parentId, elementTag, elementId, html) {
var p = document.getElementById(parentId);
var newElement = document.createElement(elementTag);
newElement.setAttribute('class', elementId);
newElement.innerHTML = html;
p.appendChild(newElement);
}


function ps_add() 
{

var pv = document.getElementById('ps_places').value;
var prv = document.getElementById('ps_price').value;

if((pv != "") && (prv != ""))
{
ps_id++;

addElement("display1", "span", ps_id, "- ");
addElement("display1", "label", ps_id, pv);
addElement("display1", "span", ps_id, " :  ");
addElement("display1", "label", ps_id, prv);
addElement("display1", "span", ps_id, "    ");
addElement("display1", "button", ps_id, "Remove");
addElement("display1", "br", ps_id, "");

var input1 = document.createElement("input");
input1.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
input1.setAttribute("class", "ps_id");
input1.setAttribute("name", "ps_places[]");
input1.setAttribute("value", pv);
display1.appendChild(input1);

var input2 = document.createElement("input");
input2.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
input2.setAttribute("class", "ps_id");
input2.setAttribute("name", "ps_price[]");
input2.setAttribute("value", prv);
display1.appendChild(input2);
}
document.getElementById('ps_places').value= ""; 
document.getElementById('ps_price').value= "";  
}
```

Comment: What about the `jQuery` tag? was it added by mistake perhaps?

Comment: i also accept jquery response as sometimes it can be more concise

Comment: @user2305415 Did my solution work for you?

Answer (score 3):

As you have added [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery), I would assume you use jQuery. You can remove all the elements by their classname using this:

```
$(".classname").remove();
```

If it was by mistake, and if you need a pure JavaScript solution, you can use this:

```
elems = document.querySelectorAll(".classname");
for (var elem in elems)
  elems[elem].parentNode.removeChild(elems[elem]);
```

Comment: Thanks, but how to handle with a click on a button that is dynamically generated , because when i put this code : $("button").click(function()
{
   alert('ok');
});                                                                                                                  The button is not detected as it was generated

Comment: @user2305415 Did you put it inside `$(document).ready(function () {})`?

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
         $('body').on('click', 'button.ps_id', function() {
  alert('ok');
        $(".ps_id").remove();
    }); 
 });

Comment: No that's not right. Can you [edit] your question and add the code @user2305415?

Comment: @user2305415 Do this. Go to http://jsbin.com and create a model of what you have currently.

Comment: @user2305415 Is it fine to use jQuery for you?

Comment: Yes but if it is also possible in js it's ok because, i have searched previously similar questions and they often responded in jquery so i thought that maybe in js it's too tricky. I was also looking to this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359018/in-jquery-how-to-attach-events-to-dynamic-html-elements

Comment: Very simple one. You need to delgate the events for this. I can help you with this. What exactly your script does and what you want the output to be? @user2305415 The JSBin is complicated. Give the me the final HTML inside the div id you wanna see?

Comment: No it's practical with jsbin, for example you can enter whatever country and then for the price whatever number.